# Custom grid with custom DAC, Multiple keys adding unwanted rows

Tags: acumatica

I've created a very simple data entry grid, I'm having an issue when I attempt to assign more than 1 isKey value in the attributes on my custom DAC. I have two fields that I need to be unique as a pair, Direct customer and Indirect customer. When I add the IsKey = true to both Direct/Indirect the grid functions abnormally and adds two rows, one with a missing indirect.

When I remove one Iskey the grid functions fine, only when the second key is added the bug occurs. I'm trying to use Direct

Below bug added empty row when using two IsKey=true on Direct Customer and Indirect Customer.
[image: When two Iskey =true are assigned]

Below when only one key is used on Direct Customer, correct functionality with no duplicate row.
[image: Using one IsKey on Direct Customer]

Data View Declaration 
[image]

Modified SQL Table for make Direct and Indirect customers to be a Primary Key

[image]

DAC declaration of the keys:

```
    #region RecordID

    [PXDBIdentity()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Record ID")]
    public int? RecordID { get; set; }

    public class recordID : IBqlField{}

    #endregion


    #region DirectCustomer

    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Direct Customer")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(PX.Objects.AR.Customer.bAccountID),
        typeof(PX.Objects.AR.Customer.acctCD),
        typeof(PX.Objects.AR.Customer.acctName),
        SubstituteKey = typeof(PX.Objects.AR.Customer.acctName))]
    public int? DirectCustomer { get; set; }

    public class directCustomer : IBqlField{}

    #endregion


    #region IndirectCustomer

    [PXDBString(100,IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Indirect Customer")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<PX.Objects.AR.Customer.acctCD,
    Where<PX.Objects.CR.BAccountExt.usrIndirectCust, Equal<True>>>),
        typeof(PX.Objects.AR.Customer.acctCD),
        typeof(PX.Objects.AR.Customer.acctName),
    SubstituteKey = typeof(PX.Objects.AR.Customer.acctName))]
    public string IndirectCustomer { get; set; }

    public class indirectCustomer : IBqlField{}

    #endregion
```

Comment: Can you post your DataView declaration?

Comment: You should also use IsKey on the record no: [PXDBIdentity(IsKey=true)]

Comment: I want DirectCustomer && IndirectCustomer to be a key as a pair. If i add isKey=true on the recordID it won't recognize when users have input duplicate key pairs since RecordID is unique.

Comment: Added a screenshot of my data view

Comment: RecordID won't be unique if you don't set it as a key field.

Comment: Check DB too to make sure DAC key fields match DB key fields.

Comment: RecordID in my instance is an auto-incremented value on the DB side. In my case it will be unique every entry, setting it as a Key field will go against when i'm trying to achieve. I will check my DB keys to see if it will resolve this issue.

Comment: Post updated, Adding the two columns as primary key did not resolve the issue Gif attached above to show error.